# why the default auto created sql tables column length is -1 in azure data factory?? and how to make it fixed?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, sqldatatypes, maxlength

I am trying to read data from csv to azure sql db using copy activity. I have selected auto create option for destination table in sink dataset properties. 
copy activity is working fine but all columns are getting created with nvarchar(max) or length -1. I dont want -1 length as default length for my auto created sink table columns.
Does any one know how to change column length or create fixed length columns while auto table creation in azure data factory?

Answer (score 0):

As you have clearly detailed, the `auto create table` option in the copy data activity is going to create a table with generic column definitions. You can run the copy activity initially in this way and then return to the target table and run T-SQL statements to further define the desired column definitions. There is no option to define table schema with the `auto create table` option.

`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name new_data_type(size);`

Clearly, the new column definition(s) must match the data that has been initially copied via the first copy activity but this is how you would combine the `auto create table` option and resulting in clearly defined column definitions.

It would be useful if you created a [Azure Data Factory UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) entry to request that the auto create table functionality include creation of column definitions as a means of saving the time needed to go back an manually alter the columns to meet specific requirements, etc.

Comment: But what if my table contains more than 100 columns? We can not run alter query for each column

Comment: This is a limitation of Data Factory and detailing the use case in UserVoice feature request will help communicate the scenario.

Comment: Could you please explain more about UserVoice feature??

Comment: UserVoice is a forum specifically for requesting new features for a specific product. It is a means for communicating with the product group and for other customers to up vote and further suggest a desire for a particular feature.